# Parallel For to Export Snapshots

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

is it possible to easily parallelize a for loop in python to help me export my snapshots faster. I cannot find any easy way and I am not even sure it is possible. Thanks for any help in advance!

```
for i in range(393849):
plt.plot(xpar[0:i],ypar[0:i],color='g')
plt.grid(True)
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim(2.9962,3.006)
axes.set_ylim(-0.002,0.028)
filename='snaps/{}.jpg'.format(i)
plt.savefig(filename)
```

Comment: do you need to repaint a subplot on each iteration?

Comment: unfortunately yes...

Comment: Can you write `xpar[]` and `ypar[]` to a file easily enough? Then you could use **GNU Parallel** to run 4 or 8 (or however many CPU cores you have) independent instances of the Python interpreter, each doing a subset of the plots...

Comment: thanks fot he answer! Of course i can. How would I go by using GNU Parallel ? Any further help would be awesome!